# php str_replace question

Tags: php, str-replace

Strange one, I must be missing something.

```
$city = "vancouver";

$insert1 = "https://www.site.ca/buy/vancouver/28130965/";    

$url2 = str_replace('/$city/','index.php?deal=',$insert1);
```

https://www.site.ca/buy/vancouver/28130965/ returned?

Comment: You are using single quotes. Use double quotes `"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [interpolate variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) only in double quotes. Use:

```
str_replace("/$city/", 'index.php?deal=', $insert1);
```

Or:

```
str_replace('/' . $city . '/', 'index.php?deal=', $insert1);
```